# Local Notifications Custom Time Interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to implement local notifications for a calendar-esque application, and I've hit a barrier with reminder intervals. Local notifications seem to only take NSCalendarUnit constants as repeat intervals ( see http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval ), as opposed to the typical NSTimeInterval value.

The application that I'm trying to develop would be severely restricted if I'm limited to NSCalendarUnit constants ( which are listed here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit ). Is there any way that I can set custom time intervals in a local notification?

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.  You don't mention why you would be severely restricted if using NSCalendarUnit.  Perhaps you can give an example of a repeat interval that you feel isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to schedule multiple LocalNotifications separated by your time frame, until they fix that bug. I am pretty sure I saw that someone filed it as a bug in the Apple Developer forums